# What does the background color of a badge mean?

Tags: support, badges

When looking through my badges, I noticed that some badges have a silver background while most have a black background. This occurs for both bronze and silver badges. All of my gold badges have the black background. **What does the different background color mean, if anything?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Silver badges are Tag badges

As can be seen on the [Badges page](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges).

All other badges come up as black.

The reason you have no gold badges that are silver is because you haven't answered enough questions in one tag to get it. Your two closest are [marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel) and [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) which are 117 and 135 questions off, and 307 and 210 up-votes off, respectively

Comment: Ah, okay. So if it's a generic badge it's black, but if it's tag specific it's silver. That makes sense. Is that explained anywhere on the site help, and I just missed it when I looked, or is that one of those nifty little hidden gems?

Comment: I think it's just a hidden gem. If you scroll through the badges page linked above, you'll see it's nothing more than convenience I guess, black for things you do, silver for your expertise in a field kinda thing

Comment: @Omegacron I've always thought of it as tag badges looking a bit like tags. If you look on [this page](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze), for instance, the backgrounds of the tag badges and the tags themselves look pretty similar.

Comment: @Randal'Thor, I'd sort of made the connection, but never really noticed it.